# sass --watch with automatic minify?

Tags: css, sass, minify

Is there a way to run:

`sass --watch a.scss:a.css`

but have `a.css` end up being minified?

How would I avoid having to run a separate minification step as I compile my stylesheet?

Answer (score 653, accepted):

```
sass --watch a.scss:a.css --style compressed
```

**Consult the documentation for updates:**

- https://sass-lang.com/guide
- https://sass-lang.com/documentation/cli/dart-sass#style

Comment: You can also minify "plain" css this way: `sass --watch a.css:a.min.css --style compressed --scss`

Comment: All of the output styles are listed [here](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#output_style) (nested, expanded, compact, and compressed)

Comment: Can I get outputs in combination of styles like; I need compressed and expanded outputs as well. How to do that?

Comment: Curiously, the output of `--style compressed` is still not as compact as some online minifiers.

Comment: This works for me to have sass create both a non-minified and minified css file at the same time `sass --watch sass/style.scss:css/style.css --watch css/style.css:css/style.min.css --style compressed --scss`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in the latest version 3.5.4 of Sass?

Comment: @AlexWright when I run now your code both file have the same result, style.css & style.min.css both are minified :'(

Answer (score 29):

If you are using [JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/) editors like [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), [PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/), [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) etc. Use the following settings in Settings > File Watchers.
[image]

1. Convert **`style.scss`** to **`style.css`** set the arguments

   ```
   --no-cache --update $FileName$:$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
   ```

   and output paths to refresh

   ```
   $FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
   ```
2. Convert **`style.scss`** to compressed **`style.min.css`** set the arguments

   ```
   --no-cache --update $FileName$:$FileNameWithoutExtension$.min.css --style compressed
   ```

   and output paths to refresh

   ```
   $FileNameWithoutExtension$.min.css
   ```

Answer (score 13):

If you're using compass:

```
compass watch --output-style compressed
```

Comment: This is a compass command and not just sass. You're assuming that compass is being used when it may not be.

Comment: This works for me too because I'm using compass instead of just sass.

Comment: Those who gave downvote just for because this code is compass should think again if the downvote is really necessary for him

Comment: Why would people downvote this answer? This was exactly what I was searching for in the first place and I am pretty sure I am not the only one because `minify compass output` Google search leads here.

Comment: @fedmich because compass was never mentioned in the original question, and since this answer lacks any explanation what the actual command does it si not helpful, if you don't use compass. I did not downvote, but I gues that is the reason, and this would be a perfectly fine answer, if there were at least a few words of description.

Answer (score 4):

**There are some different way to do that**

```
sass --watch --style=compressed main.scss main.css
```

or

```
sass --watch a.scss:a.css --style compressed
```

or

By Using visual studio code extension **live sass compiler**

[see more](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/cli/dart-sass#style)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me :

```
sass --watch --style=compressed a.scss:a.css
```

[Reference](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/cli/dart-sass)

Comment: Guys! Just an update. Nowadays it will work like this: `sass --watch styles.scss styles.css --style compressed`.